# Do objects share the same memory address by default

Tags: kotlin, object, memory, shared-memory, equality

what does this behavior mean?

```
var string1 = "hello"
var string2 = "hello"
println(string1 == string2) // return true
println(string1 === string2) // return true
```

since

> **equality**: determines if two objects contain the same state. (==)
>
> **identity**: determines whether two objects share the same memory address. (===)

do they share the same memory address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **YES**, they share the same memory address.

Next description is applicable for **Kotlin/JVM**. When you declare a new string, there are some interesting things that happen behind the scenes. This is a basic string declaration. We create a new string variable called `string1` and give it a value:

```
var string1 = "hello"
```

It will allocate space in the memory for the literal value **hello**. This area in memory is called the **string constant pool**. It's like a pool of string values that are available to other parts of the program.
Now, if you created another variable, say `string2`, and ALSO gave it a value of **hello** Kotlin re-uses the value that's already in the pool.
The string constant pool sits inside a section of memory is called the **heap**. This is a part of memory that is used for run-time operations, working with classes and objects. Think of a heap like a patch of garden soil you can easily take dirt and plants from as you plant a garden. Kotlin places these new objects there. If you create a hundred more objects, Kotlin will create a hundred more literals atop the heap.

I would use **Referential equality (===)** only to check whether variables pointing to the same object or not.

Comment: That's a good description of the JVM; string constant folding is part of the Java spec, so must be true for Kotlin/JVM.  — But is it guaranteed to be true for Kotlin/JS or Kotlin/native too?  (I think I'd be very wary of any program which used referential equality in that way.)

Comment: Didn't check that, but it is a good notice, I wouldn't rely on **Referential equality** at all unless you need to compare references and check whether it is the same object or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they share the same memory address. If we already have "hello", new "hello" won't be created by

```
var string2 = "hello"
```

If you created new string by constructor

```
var string2 = String("hello")
```

then

```
println(string1 === string2)
```

return false

Read about Java String Pool https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-pool

Answer (score 0):

I did some findings for your good question.

As in [Kotlin's Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#referential-equality), primitive types are treated same in `==` and `===` both.

But for custom objects, they work in a different way.
`==` compares structure and `===` checks reference.

> ```
>     fun main(args: Array<String>) {
>     val v1 = Temp("world")
>     val v2 = Temp("world")
>
>     println(v1 == v2)// true
>     println(v1 === v2)// false
>     }
>
>
>     data class Temp(var val1: String)
> ```